# How to display all created variables in Pig Latin?

Tags: apache-pig

After I run this command in Pig Latin

```
abc = group xyz by n
def = group pqr by m
```

abc variable will be created which will store values present in xyz grouped by coloumn n and similarly def will be created. Now if I want to all the variables that are created, is there any command to display?

Comment: See this?
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/16802705/2308683

Comment: just use `dump abc` to display all the data stored under abc